# Problem with select, v-model that change other component

Tags: vue.js

I have this code with vue.js. I simplified the code for the question.
The problem is WHEN I CHANGE THE PROVINCE, AUTOMATICALLY MY SECOND SELECT 
 "selectProCongeFam" CHANGE TOO. I don't know why exactly.

Here is the code :

```js
   
   
   const deduction = {!! json_encode($deduction->toArray()) !!};
    const provinces = {!! json_encode($provinces) !!};

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: function () {
            return {
                
                provinces: provinces,
                province: deduction['province']
                  
            }
        } 
    })
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Province
       <select class="form-control"
         name="province" id="province" v-model="province">
        <option v-for="(name,value) in provinces" :value="value">
         @{{name}}
        </option>
       </select>
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="selectProCongeFam">@lang('form.extFamily')
       <select id="selectProCongeFam" name="proCongeFam"
         class="form-control">
        <option value="0"
          :selected="deduction['proCongeFam'] == 0">@lang('form.no')</option>
        <option value="1" :selected="deduction['proCongeFam'] == 1">@lang('form.yes')</option>
        <option value="2" :selected="deduction['proCongeFam'] == 2">@lang('form.yesbutILD')</option>
        <option value="3" :selected="deduction['proCongeFam'] == 3">@lang('form.AMConly')</option>
       </select>
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide a working example as the above code isn't working and requires some data that you haven't provided, this data is required to show us the undesired behavior of your code. Thanks

Comment: Can you update your snippet to make the code behave as you said?